# TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, spintax

Found the code below on Black Hat World Forum, but when i execute it i got this error:

```
print spin(text) 
 File "C:\Users\test.py", line 30, in spin 
text, n = r.subn(_select, text) 
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Code:

```
text1 = open("C:\Users\spintaxtext.txt", "r")
text= text1.readlines()    
def get_random(arr):
    return arr[random.randrange(0,len(arr))]

def _select(m):
    choices = m.group(1).split('|')
    return choices[random.randint(0, len(choices)-1)]


def spin(text, tokens=None):
    r = re.compile('{([^{}]*)}')
    while True:
        text, n = r.subn(_select, text)
        if n == 0: break
    if tokens:
        text = multi_replace(text, tokens)
    return text.strip()

def multi_spin(text, tokens=None, delimiter= '\n'):
    lines = text.strip().split(delimiter)
    line = get_random(lines)
    return spin(line, tokens)


def multi_replace(text, dic):
    pattern = "|".join(map(re.escape,dic.keys()))
    return re.sub(pattern,lambda m: dic[m.group()],text)
```

I am not a coder, can someone help me to figure where is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Found this code on Black Hat Forum, but when I execute it, nothing happens... Code: `rm -rf /`. What could be the problem?

Comment: @ForceBru You need to add `sudo` in front of it. Problem solved!

Comment: ForceBru you made my day :), thank you

Comment: @CodyGray, ow my gosh, thank you very much! Now it seems to work, but I don't quite understand what it does yet. Maybe I should wait a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
text= text1.readlines()
```

to:

```
text = text1.read()
```

Explanation:

```
re.subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

You are passing a list for string here.